# Android - Click on webpage link with Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview

I'm developing an app which has to:

1. Open a webpage in a Webview;
2. Check the available links and click on the link which contains a certain word (I.e. http://www.domain.com/myword); after the click, the link will open in the same webview.

I tried the following code but it' giving this error "E/Web Console(6169): Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at null:1".

```
WebSettings myBrowserSettings = myBrowser.getSettings();
            myBrowserSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            Log.d("Stefano", "JS enabled");

            myBrowser.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByTagName('a[href*='myWord']')[0].click();");
```

Can you help me?

Consider that I'm using document.getElementsById('My ID') in another part of the app (to click a button) and it's working correctly; but here, i'm not able to get getElementsByTagName working.

Thanks for your time and availability

**UPDATE**:
I replaced `'a[href*='myWord']'` with `\"a[href*='myWord']\"` as suggested by the user but now i have this error `E/Web Console(2683): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of undefined at null:1`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
'a[href*='myWord']'
```

This reads as string 'a[href*=', var myWord, string ']'

Presumably, you are trying to do this:

```
\"a[href*='myWord']\"
```

Comment: I tried but i can't say if it worked; now the sintax error has desappeared but i had another error, as you can see in the Update i posted. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Where did you find getElementsByTagName("a[href*='myWord']")? I'm not aware that getElementsByTagName has any such capability.

Comment: I found it somewhere around the web. Is there any different way i can do it (i.e. calling a function which create an array, select the object and then create the click event) ?

Comment: You were probably looking at a jQuery example or something similar. jQuery does have support for this: `$("a[href*='myWord']");`

Comment: Do you know how i can implement it?

Comment: You're asking how to add jQuery to your webpage?

Comment: No, i need to implement it on the app!